# jquery-based standalone port knocker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssh, port

I am working on a small project and need to provide an alternative method for my team members to port knock on a non-production server and open port 22 for SSH traffic (access closes again after 10 minutes). As some methods of knocking don't work for different users on different devices, we needed to create a 'knock client of last resort' that can be opened as a stand-alone web page and initiate the knock sequence.  Of course this file would NEVER be put on a web server for security reasons.

I'm new to jQuery, javascript, and CSS, but was able to get this to work. However, it doesn't work in all browsers, and sometimes we have to reboot if it is no longer working on a particular machine.

After a lot of searching, I’m really not sure how to improve my code while keeping all the functionality contained within a single html file. I would really appreciate some input.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gain Access- Beta version 1.0</title>
<style>
* {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
#top{
    margin-left:80px;
}
#heading {
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#subhead {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size:12px;
}
button {
    font-size:16px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
#button {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#status {
    margin-left:90px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#knocks {
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:14px;
    color:blue;

}
#portals {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-top: 155px;
    display:none;
}
.tinyimg {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#knocks').append('<p>Knocking...</p>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:1111/test/url.jpg/" />');
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 1 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 500);    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:2222/test/url.jpg/" />');
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 2 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 3500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:3333/test/url.jpg" />');
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 3 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 6500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:4444/test/url.jpg" />');
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 4 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 9500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:5555/test/url.jpg/" />');
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 5 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 12000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knocking is complete... <br>Proceed to site: <a href='http://secureurl.someurl.com'>http://secureurl.someurl.com/a></p>");
        }, 13000);
});
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
<p><span id="heading">Gain Access</span><br><span id="subhead">Beta version 1.0</span></p>
</div>
<button type="button">Click to Knock</button>
<div id="portals"></div> <!--The image references created by the port knocks land in this div.-->
<p id="status">Status:</p>
<div id="knocks"><p>Click button to knock</p></div> <!--The status updates generated concurrently with each port knock are displayed here.-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GET` requests for images to port knock on your server. I assume the server does not reply to these requests and even filters them, so they will eventually time out.

Some browsers might be reluctant to perform the same request if the previous attempts timed out. They may also implement a queue and only send a few requests at the same time, which can cause problems if these requests are still pending when you have to send the next part of your knock (standard TCP timeout being 30 seconds).

If at all possible, reimplement your knocking protocol with [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

If you're stuck with images, try appending `"?" + $.now()`to your URLs so they become unique for each request. It might help preventing the browser from giving up on a specific request.

Comment: chances are that he's just hitting the "two connections" per host limit in HTTP

Comment: @Alnitak, doesn't that limit only apply to requests made to the same host on the same port?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm really new to coding, so I'm hoping for a little further clarification. I'm hoping to implement this with jQuery and javascript without having to learn WebSockets. Can you help me understand how to "append '?' + $.now()" to my URLs? Are we talking something like this?:

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
  $('#portals').append('<img class="tinyimg" src="https://some.url.com:1111/test/url.jpg/ + $.now()" />');
  $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 1 of 5 complete...</p>");
  }, 500);

Comment: ...or do I need to setup url variables and call them within each function?

Comment: Yup, we're talking about something like `append('<img class="tinyimg" src="some.url.com:1111/test/url.jpg?' + $.now() + '" />');` (note the quotes).

Comment: I was able to get the modified urls generated. Blocked, but at this point I'm working with IT to see if they have a config issue. Thanks for the varied URL suggestion. I'll keep an eye out for other options and welcome additional input.

Comment: Stuck again. Got it working in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox. When watching the calls come into the targeted server, when it works I see the calls come in sequentially to ports 1, 2, 3, 4, and then 5. However, in Firefox, the first request goes to ports 1, 1, and then 2; other request executed shortly thereafter only ping port 1, just once each. I've tried using the jquery.ajax call, tried adding timeout parameters, and am still stuck. I'm continuing to research but would appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: As this seems to be a firefox issue, trying to isolate that here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103952/firefox-not-completing-series-of-calls-when-previous-attempts-failed)