# Firefox not completing series of calls when previous attempts failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a script that pings a series of urls with a GET method. I only want to ping them each once and do not expect a response. My script works in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox won't complete the later requests.

Is there a way to trigger Firefox to make a series of calls (five, to be precise) once each, and not care if they fail? It seems that Firefox won't complete the series of requests when the first ones fail.

I'm working in javascript and jQuery, with a little jQuery.ajax() thrown in. I've searched, to no avail and have reached the limit of my beginner's skill set. Any insight would be appreciated.

(If you're interested in the full scope, there's code at [jquery-based standalone port knocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097036/jquery-based-standalone-port-knocker))

Thank you.

---

Update:

After further research, I believe the issue is that Firefox isn't handling the calls truly asynchronously. I have versions of code making the pings with img calls, iframe url calls, and ajax calls to work in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox they're not behaving as I need them to.

Our server monitoring for the knock sequence should see requests come sequentially to ports 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (as it does when using Chrome or Safari) but in Firefox, no matter which method I've tried, I see the first attempt ping port 1 twice, then port 2, and on subsequent attempts I only see it ping port 1. My status updates appear as expected, but the server isn't receiving the calls in the order it needs them. It seems that Firefox is retrying failed calls rather than executing each one once, in sequence, which is what I need it to do.

Here is a sample of my script using a simple jquery.ajax call method. It works in Safari and Chrome, but doesn't achieve the desired result in Firefox. While all my code runs and I can see the status updates (generated with the jquery.append function), the request aren't sent once each, sequentially to my server.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#knocks').append('<p>Knocking...</p>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'https://example.sample.com:1111'});
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 1 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 500);    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'https://example.sample.com:2222'});
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 2 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 3500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'https://example.sample.com:3333'});
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 3 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 6500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'https://example.sample.com:4444'});
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 4 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 9500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'https://example.sample.com:5555'});
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knock 5 of 5 complete...</p>");
        }, 12000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#knocks').append("<p>Knocking is complete... <br>Proceed to site: <a href='http://example-url.sample-url.com'>http://example-url.sample-url.com</a></p>");
        }, 13000);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: How are you making the series of calls? Could you provide some code?

Comment: Does this: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu3W/1/ work in your version of Firefox?

Comment: After further research, I believe the issue is that Firefox isn't handling the calls truly asynchronously. I have versions of code making the pings with img calls, iframe url calls, and ajax calls to work in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox they're not behaving as I need them to. Our server monitoring for the knock sequence should see requests come sequentially to ports 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (as it does when using Chrome or Safari) but in Firefox, no matter which method I've tried, I see the first attempt ping port 1 twice, then port 2, and on subsequent attempts I only see it ping port 1.

Comment: @fet - I've edited my question to include the jquery.ajax version of my code for my calls. I've also tried specifying a post type of GET, POST, or PUT. In addition, I have had versions of my code using jQuery to append html referencing the needed urls as image or iframe calls. These have all worked in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. I've also been able to do variations on the call urls using http or https and either ...com:1111 or ...com:1111/test/url.jpg or "...com:1111?' + $.now() + '"

Comment: @TildalWave Thanks. Yes, that works fine for me in Firefox. I've been able to get the on-screen components to work correctly consistently, but the calls aren't individual and in sequence. I've modified my original question post to clarify further. I appreciate your time and input.

Comment: @ethagnawl Thanks for the test. Yes, that works. I've updated my original question to better clarify that the on-screen components of my code work, but I believe Firefox is not executing the url calls as I would like it to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing there's no real answer to your question and you'd probably want to move on, I though I'd give you some suggestions as a starting point.

For your function calls to truly execute in a sequential order (or *synchronous*, *in-order*, *blocking*,...) you will have to make sure you issue all the subsequent function calls (AJAX requests in your case) once the proceeding requests completed (either succeed, or failed, in which case you might not want to proceed with the next in-order call and issue a completely separate response).

The way you're doing it now isn't considered *synchronous*, instead it is actually *asynchronous, delayed* (or 'in the background' with a timeout). This might cause all kinds of problems when you expect your AJAX calls to execute synchronously (blocking) at your server end. From browsers re-issuing failed or timed-out requests (for various reasons, depending on their feature set and how they handle failed requests, caching,...) to preemptively issuing requests and caching results when some pre-fetchers are enabled (or however they're calling it in FF), then re-issuing them again if pre-fetcher failed. I believe this is similar to what you observed in Firefox and might be the main culprit for this unexpected behavior. As you can't control what features end user enables or disables in their browser, or what new features they implement in future versions, you can't really expect your server calls to execute asynchronous by delaying their calls with `setTimeout`, even if they appear to be doing so in other browsers (probably because of your server responding fast enough for them to appear as such).

In your code, the second call would only appear to be executing *synchronously* (waiting for the first one to complete) for up to half a second, the third request for up to 3 seconds and a half, and so on. But even if `setTimeout` was blocking execution (which it doesn't), which external request would it be waiting for? The first one, or the second one? I think you get what I'm trying to say and why your code doesn't work as expected.

Instead, you should either issue subsequent AJAX calls through your server's response (which is actually the point of using AJAX, otherwise there's no need for it), or preferably, create an external listener function that will handle these calls according to the status and/or return values of your previous external calls. If you need to handle failed requests as well and continue execution regardless, then the external listener (with preset execution stack timeout) is the way to go, as you obviously wouldn't be able to depend on response of failed requests.

You see, browsers have no problems issuing multiple concurrent requests and delaying them with `setTimout` doesn't stop pre-fetchers to try and cache their responses for later use either. It also doesn't issue requests in a blocking manner, the next one waiting for the previous one to finish, as you expected them to. Most will be happy to utilize up to a certain number of concurrent connection (~10 on client machines, a lot more on servers) in an effort to speed-up the download and/or page rendering process, and some obviously have even more advanced caching mechanism in place for this very same reason, Firefox being merely one of them.

I hope this clears things up a bit and you'll be able to rewrite your code to work as expected. As we have no knowledge of how your server-side code is supposed to work, you'll have to write it yourself, though. There are however plenty of threads on SE discussing similar techniques that you might decide on using, and you can always ask another question if you get stuck and we'll be glad to help.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response, especially the clarification that setTimeout cannot be expected to block requests from being executed until the set time. I had thought that the ajax call would be sending a single request so long as one did not set asynch=false. I'm digesting it and will try to evaluate how to get ajax to execute the series of calls (my attempts yesterday were unsuccessful, but I'm even newer to ajax than I am to javascript and jQuery). The server will not be issuing a response and I believe that adding code on the server side will not be possible.